# How to initialize array with user input?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to initialize my array upon user input. Say if the user enters an item into the text field and then they press the add button, I want the string from the text field to go into the array.

```
class CustomList : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var thingsList: MutableList<String>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_list)

        addItemBtn.setOnClickListener { 
            if(item_text_field.text.toString() == "") {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Must enter text first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                val item = item_text_field.text.toString()
                thingsList = item
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/add.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need of lateinit here, and unless you initialize the variable you cannot add items to it. You can instead use [lazy](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy) to initialize it when needed. And the [MutableList.add()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/add.html) is used to add items to a list.

```kotlin
// thingsList will be initialized whenever accessed for the first time
val thingsList by lazy { mutableListOf<String>() }

addItemBtn.setOnClickListener { 
    if(item_text_field.text.toString() == "") {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Must enter text first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        // use add on the MutableList to add times into it
        thingsList.add(item_text_field.text.toString())
    }
}
```